# flask-mail "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first" error when deployed

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-mail

I'm trying to use flask-mail to send an email to a user. When testing on localhost, the email send no problem. However, when I deploy to heroku I get the following error:

```
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479869+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-08 16:10:19,478] ERROR in app: Exception on /cancellation_email [POST]    
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479879+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479880+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 76, in cancellation_email
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479881+00:00 app[web.1]: conn.send(msg)
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479882+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 188, in 
send
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479882+00:00 app[web.1]: self.host.sendmail(sanitize_address(envelope_from or message.sender),
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479882+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 885, in sendmail
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479883+00:00 app[web.1]: raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479885+00:00 app[web.1]: smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [MN2PR10CA0035.namprd10.prod.outlook.com]', 'jrogers@intuitautomation.com')
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479886+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479887+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479887+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479887+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479888+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in 
wsgi_app
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479888+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479889+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in 
full_dispatch_request
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479889+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479889+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479890+00:00 app[web.1]: return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in 
full_dispatch_request
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479890+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in 
dispatch_request
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479890+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)       
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479891+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 76, in cancellation_email
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479891+00:00 app[web.1]: conn.send(msg)
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479891+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 152, in 
__exit__
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479891+00:00 app[web.1]: self.host.quit()
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479891+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1002, in quit
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: res = self.docmd("quit")
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 429, in docmd
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: self.putcmd(cmd, args)
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 376, in putcmd
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: self.send(f'{s}{CRLF}')
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 363, in send
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479893+00:00 app[web.1]: raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
2022-03-08T16:10:19.479893+00:00 app[web.1]: smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
2022-03-08T16:10:19.480718+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.15.18 - - [08/Mar/2022:16:10:19 +0000] "POST /cancellation_email HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://www.intuitautomation.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is the relevant code from my app.py file:

```
from models import setup_email
from flask_mail import Message
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))

mail = setup_email(app)

@app.route('/cancellation_email', methods=["POST"])
def cancellation_email():
  data=request.get_json()
  email=data[0].lower()
  date=data[1]
  time=data[2]

  with mail.connect() as conn:
    msg = Message(subject="Thank You for Booking with Us!", sender="jrogers@intuitautomation.com", recipients = [email])
    template = jinja_env.get_template('email.html')
    msg.html = template.render(data={'email':email,'date':date,'time':time})
    conn.send(msg)

  response = make_response(jsonify("ok"))
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

  return response
```

And finally the relevant code in my models.py:

```
from flask_mail import Mail

def setup_email(app):
  app.config['MAIL_SERVER']="smtp.office365.com"
  app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
  app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
  app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
  app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
  app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
  return Mail(app)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get "Client not authenticated" did u set your env variables MAIL_... ?

Comment: I did set the env variables but they were not getting registered. I replaced them with the actual email and password and it worked. Not sure why the env variables wont work.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-config-vars did u set env vars like is described in this article?